# Python JSON String (containing hex) to HEX

Tags: python, json, string, hex

I'm trying to get random hex value between range of hexes:

`random.randint(0xfff000, 0xffffff)`

I got the range limits from JSON, as a string.

`{"range": "0xfff000,0xffffff"}`

How can I convert these strings(after splitting) to hexadecimal values?

Comment: Note that "values" are neither decimal, nor binary, nor yet hexidecimal. It is only the representation, e.g. strings, that have place-value at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the built-in [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function with a base of `16`:

```
>>> int('0xfff000', 16)
16773120
>>> int('0xfff000', 16) == 0xfff000
True
```

Comment: +1, I never knew that `int` accepted strings prefixed like that.

Comment: Yeah I had to double check it, was about to write an answer that stripped the `0x` off first but it is nice that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilise the following:

```
from random import randint

d = {"range": "0xfff000,0xffffff"}
print randint(*(int(i, 16) for i in d['range'].split(',')))
# 16775837
```

And then expand that to customise your own *random integer* function, eg:

```
from random import randint
from functools import partial

d = {"range": "0xfff000,0xffffff"}
my_random = partial(randint, *(int(i, 16) for i in d['range'].split(',')))
print [my_random() for n in range(5)]
# [16776381, 16774349, 16776922, 16773212, 16775873]
```